# songs blog in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogs

Hi folks I wish to start one blog using wordpress. It ll contain songs, playlists, song serch.
What are the steps i want to do?

thanks

Comment: If this is programming related please add more context. Atm it looks off topic to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If WordPress hasn't been installed
1 - choose a good host for your WordPress installation. I've been using dreamhost.com
2 - Install WordPress ( dreamhost has a very WordPress installation process )

If it's already installed: 
1 - create the pages you need. this will also give you your site navigation
2 - upload your files in the media library
3 - start creating pages containing media library files

We can dive deeper, but these are the first steps.